# enabling '&' and special characters in url

Tags: asp.net

How could i enable '&' and some others specials characters like '*,@,%' in url without changing registry value to allow restricted characters in iis. Is there any solution that can be solved through web.config file in asp.net?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is encode your characters for use in a URL. You can do that using [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't ever be using those characters in the url directly. You need to URL encode the values in order for them to exist in the url.

for example:

```
Server.UrlEncode("Dog & Cat");
```

Will produce:

> Dog%20%26%20Cat

Which is legal within the url.

Comment: this approach is some what feasible to encode the url. but in my case it is not enough. I am searching more easy method through web.config file.

Comment: @Arvind: It would be good to have an example of why you need to have illegal characters in the url in the first place? URL encoded values in the url will safely translate back to the original characters across all browsers / platforms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to ASP.NET Request Validation blocking postbacks containing those characters, you can disable it at the Page level by adding the following property to the page's declaration:

```
ValidateRequest="false"
```

For example:

```
<%@ Page Title="Page Title" Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

Disabling this can be a security risk though if you are not careful to perform your own validation of the postback's form input.

Comment: IE will not accept urls with a % if its not a part of a encoded string. Try this http://www.google.com/%b%hhjhj in IE

Comment: thank for response. this post is helpful but i need to make from web.config file. In .netframework 4 there is option of  requestPathInvalidCharacters = "". But no in framework3.5 is there any possible way to do from web.config.

Comment: @Arvind: Can you please explain why you need to have invalid characters in the url in the first place?

Comment: i have list of category in menu. when i click one of them it redirect to next aspx page name after that category name. the problem occurs when i make the category name containing such characters like "Book & copy", men's collection, special items* etc. When i click one of them in menu it should redirect to next page like Book & copy.aspx, men's collection.aspx etc In such case i get bad request error. I have got the solution by changing the registry file like

Comment: I have got the solution by changing the registry file like [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET]
"VerificationCompatibility"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters]
"AllowRestrictedChars"=dword:00000001 but it is not possible in all case. so is there any feasible solution.